# React is rendering [object Object] on the webpage instead of original value. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have tried to fetch data from API. Now trying to show the data within a table cell inside <Typography /> component. Instead of rendering original data, react is rendering [object Object]. I tried to join the data with comma.I have searched enough on the internet, haven't found desired solution. It looks like .joined() operator is not working with jsx.  How to show the original data with little bit of styling? Without the <Typography /> it's showing the original data.

```
my code example: 


import React, { Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
const Item = ({ item }) => {
  const [geofences, setGeofences] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`/api/geofences?stoppageId=${item.id}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setGeofences(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }, []);
  
  **Data I want to show on the webpage**
  return (
    geofences.map((geofence) => <Typography>{geofence.name}</Typography>).join(', ')
  );
};

export default Item;
```

on this note. the Item component is getting called inside following component.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  Table, TableRow, TableCell, TableHead, TableBody, IconButton,
} from '@mui/material';
import FmdGoodIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FmdGood';
import ShareLocationIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShareLocation';
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
//* importing child component 'Item' from stoppagesPageChild
import Item from './stoppagesPageChild';
import MapMarkers from '../map/MapMarkers';
import MapGeofence from '../map/main/MapGeofence';
import MapPositions from '../map/MapPositions';
import MapCamera from '../map/MapCamera';
import { useEffectAsync } from '../reactHelper';
import MapView from '../map/core/MapView';
import { useTranslation } from '../common/components/LocalizationProvider';
import PageLayout from '../common/components/PageLayout';
import { devicesActions } from '../store';
import SettingsMenu from './components/SettingsMenu';
import CollectionFab from './components/CollectionFab';
import CollectionActionsStoppage from './components/CollectionActionsStoppage';
import TableShimmer from '../common/components/TableShimmer';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  columnAction: {
    width: '1%',
    paddingLeft: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  containerMap: {
    flexBasis: '40%',
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  containerMain: {
    overflow: 'auto',
  },
}));

const StoppagesPage = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const t = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const routes = Object.values(useSelector((state) => state.geofences.items));
  const positions = Object.values(useSelector((state) => state.positions.items));

  const [timestamp, setTimestamp] = useState(Date.now());
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  // const [geofences, setGeofences] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onClick = useCallback((_, deviceId) => {
    dispatch(devicesActions.select(deviceId));
  }, [dispatch]);

  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);

  useEffectAsync(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/stoppages');
      if (response.ok) {
        setItems(await response.json());
      } else {
        throw Error(await response.text());
      }
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [timestamp]);

  return (
    <PageLayout menu={<SettingsMenu />} breadcrumbs={['settingsTitle', 'settingsStoppages']}>
      <div className={classes.container}>
        {selectedItem && (
        <div className={classes.containerMap}>
          <MapView>
            {/* MapCamera is moving towards selectedItem lngLat */}
            <MapCamera key={selectedItem.id} longitude={selectedItem.longitude} latitude={selectedItem.latitude} />
            <MapGeofence routes={routes} />
            <MapMarkers onClick={onClick} />
            <MapPositions positions={positions} showStatus />
          </MapView>
        </div>
        )}
        <div className={classes.containerMain}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell className={classes.columnAction} />
                <TableCell>{t('settingsStoppage')}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{t('settingsCoordinates')}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>{t('sharedRoutes')}</TableCell>
                <TableCell className={classes.columnAction} />
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {!loading ? items.map((item) => (
                <TableRow key={item.id}>
                  <TableCell className={classes.columnAction} padding="none">
                    {selectedItem === item ? (
                      <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => setSelectedItem(null)}>
                        <ShareLocationIcon fontSize="small" color="primary" />
                      </IconButton>
                    ) : (
                      <IconButton size="small" onClick={() => setSelectedItem(item)}>
                        <FmdGoodIcon fontSize="small" />
                      </IconButton>
                    )}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{item.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {
                      `Latitude: ${(item.latitude).toFixed(6)}, 
                       Longitude: ${(item.longitude).toFixed(6)}`
                    }
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    **component item is getting called here**
                    <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.columnAction} padding="none">
                    <CollectionActionsStoppage itemId={item.id} editPath="/settings/stoppage"              endpoint="stoppages" setTimestamp={setTimestamp} />
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              )) : (<TableShimmer columns={4} endAction />)}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
          <CollectionFab editPath="/settings/stoppage" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </PageLayout>
  );
};

export default StoppagesPage;
```

Comment: I remember you asking it earlier but It would be easy to understand the issue if you can create a runnable sample and share the link, you can use codesandbox / stackblitz / w/e works for you  (add code, save and share the link)

Comment: there is no technical error in this code. it just not rendering the original data rather it's rendering [object Object]. codesandbox / stackblitz can not detect the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're generating an array like shown below which you then try to join together like a string. Since `Typography` is an component this will indeed result in an string like `[object Object], [object Object]`

```js
[<Typography>geo name</Typography>, <Typography>other geo name</Typography>]
// followed by
.join(', ')
// results in
"[object Object], [object Object]"
```

Instead what you can do is something like this

```js
return (
  <>
    {geofences.map((geofence, idx) => (
      <Typography
        color={geofence.color}
        component="span"
      >
        {geofence.name}
        {idx < geofences.length ? ',' : ''}
      </Typography>
    ))}
  </>
);
```

Or if you want all the names in the same `Typography` component you could do it like this, get all the name from the object, `map` will return an array which you can perform `.join(', ')` on.

```js
return (
  <Typography>
    {geofences.map((geofence) => geofence.name).join(", ")}
  </Typography>
);
```

Comment: I have tried both of the case earlier. Nothing gonna get me the desired result. I need to set different color of mapped geofence name. so only `geofence.name `needs to be inside Typography. If i consider your first case which I tried before, It's giving me the opportunity to set different color to different name , then again it's not possible to concat (', ') after every geofence name but not after the last one. How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to show them one after another you could set the `component` prop on the `Typography` component to `span`, see the [MUI Typography docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/typography/) for more information.

Comment: can you show me in the code please!!

Comment: I hope this edit will guide you in the right direction

Comment: It didn't work. It's showing (',') comma after the last item as well.

Comment: i think the idx value remains the same throughout mapping.

Comment: No it doesn't, it is the index of the mapped value. Maybe the length should be -1 `{idx < geofences.length - 1 ? ',' : ''}` since the index starts from 0